# How to delay loading items by using RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java2

While inflating Android view I load a bunch of stuff from the background thread and inflate some views based on network responses. So I am trying to defer some of that tasks using RxJava like this

```
Single.fromCallable(() -> savedInstanceState)
           .delay(50,TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS,AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMapCompletable(this::loadVideos)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    Timber.d("on Subscribe");
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    Timber.d("on onComplete");

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    Timber.d("on onError");

                }
            });
```

And the loadVideos method is like this:

```
private Completable loadVideos(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return Completable.fromAction(() -> {
        videoPresenter.loadVideos(savedInstance);
    });
}
```

What I am finding is onSubscribe() certainly gets called, but method `videoPresenter.loadVideos` never gets called. Would appreciate if anyone can point out what I am doing wrong.

For my testing, I implemented following test that seems to work...

```
public class DelayTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Single.fromCallable(() -> "hello")
            .delay(50, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            .flatMapCompletable(new Function<String, CompletableSource>() {
                @Override
                public CompletableSource apply(String s) throws Exception {
                    return getFlatMapCompletable();
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    System.out.println("In onSubscribe");
                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    System.out.println("In onComplete");

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    System.out.println("In onError");

                }
            });
    Thread.sleep(200L);
}

private static Completable getFlatMapCompletable() {
    return Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("In flatmapCompletable");
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Do you check if savedInstanceState is null before setting up Single.fromCallable?

Comment: The problem might be in delay with mainThread, basically it looks like loadVideo will be called from main thread and for some unknown reason it isn't called

Answer (score 0):

**Delay** operator in RxJava is executed in another thread. So the rest of the execution does not wait for this one to be finished.

Take a look to some examples https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/utils/ObservableDelay.java